# Issue checking if entry in table already exists by checking zone, date and hour

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, date

I have a database with a table in which I store several values along with the zone to which it belongs, the date it is from, and the hour it is from. The table will get updated periodically, from a source that may contain both new and old data I already have, new data will be inserted, old data I already stored will be updated, since it may have changed from the time it was created and I need the newest possible.

I have no problem checking wether the zone and the hour already exists:

```
sql.CommandText = "select 'Y' from dual where exists (select * from mytable where hour= "+hour+" and zone='" + zone+ "')"
```

But If add the date to the equation it fails when it calls the ExecuteScalar method:

```
sql.CommandText = "select 'Y' from dual where exists (select * from mytable where hour = " + hour + " and zone = '" + zone+ "' and date_field = '" + datevalue + "')"
```

I have tried other methods before but none seemed to work, like doing a Select Count(*) and executing the reader or doing a merge sentence.

Any help is appreciated. I'm working on VB, .NET framework 3.5, and Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison must look like this in oracle:

```
... AND date_field = TO_DATE('27-09-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Try this, if you want to keep the string version, but using a prametrized query as Magnus has shown, circumvents the date representation problem:

```
sql.CommandText = String.Format(@"SELECT 'Y' FROM dual WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM mytable
     WHERE hour = {0} AND zone = {1} AND
           date_field = TO_DATE('{2:dd-MM-yyyy}','DD-MM-YYYY'))",
    hour, zone, datevalue);
```

Note: `datevalue` is assumed to be a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the conversion from `DateTime` to `string` is in a format that the Sql server does not recognize.
You should use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of concatenating a string with the values. Also  make sure the values are in the correct type. (`DateTime` for `datevalue` and not `string`)

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("select 'Y' from dual where exists (select * from mytable where hour = @hour and zone = @zone and date_field = @datevalue)", connection))
{
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("hour", hour));
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("zone", zone));
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("datevalue", datevalue));

  var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

This will also avoid nasty SQL injection attacks.